# jQuerify String To Find Element Fails

Tags: jquery

There is string from textarea that i wrap into jQuery and then use 'find()' to search for element:

```
var data = '<div class="page-content-wrapper"><div class="page-content"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb editor-wrapper-end">Content comes here</ul></div></div></div></div>';
var jData = jQuery(data);
jData.find('.editor-wrapper-end').length == 1
```

This works, but it fails, when data contains more than one sibling:

```
 var data = '<div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top>top menu</div><div class="page-content-wrapper"><div class="page-content"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb editor-wrapper-end">Content comes here</ul></div></div></div></div>';
 var jData = jQuery(data);
 jData.find('.editor-wrapper-end').length == 0//
```

The above fails to find element even though the element with class '.editor-wrapper-end' exists. AS one of the solutions, i was thinking to wrap the data between body tags before jQueryfy(i.e. jQuery('' + data + '')). This doesn't work because jQuery() still returns array of children. What is the best solution here? I prefer to avoid handling the loop(.each) myself because ultimately, i like to remove all tags before and after element with class editor-wrapper-end, so handling looping through each children sounds a lot of work to me. ...i just like to call jData('editor-wrapper-end') and be done. Thank You

Here is an example at http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/1/

Comment: It works fine.  The problem I see here is `assertTrue`.  Just do `console.log(jData.find('.editor-wrapper-end').length);`.  Maybe if you explained what you're trying to do then it may help.

Comment: Thank You Archer. Updated the code to remove confusition about assetTRue and added jsfiddle code snippet

Comment: Isn't this just a typo?  You've got `ckeditor-wrapper-end` but look for `editor-wrapper-end`.  If you fix that it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/7/

Comment: Archer...here is right one http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the fact that the html you are searching has the element you are searching for at root level.  jQuery's `find()` searches for matching child elements of the top-level elements.  Take this example...

```
$("<div class='mydiv'></div>").find(".mydiv");
```

That will return an empty array since `find()` looks *inside* the top-level div, which in this case is the div that we're looking for.

This, however, will return what we want...

```
$("<div class='top-level'><div class='mydiv'></div></div>").find(".mydiv");
```

`.find()` searches *inside* `div.top-level`, and this time finds what we're looking for.

So, I simply wrapped all your html inside an extra div in this example and it returns what you're looking for...

http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/11/

An alternative would be to use `.each()` and check each element to see if it has the corresponding class.  This is longer, and more code, but it means you don't have to change your initial HTML, which I guess may be more preferable.  Without context it's difficult to know, so just use what suits your needs best...

http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/12/

Comment: Thank You Archer. You are correct. Like to note that the wrapping tag cannot be '<body>' as it appears jQuery ignores it...'<div>' works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `assertTrue` does but it works fine if you replace it with `!!`
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Here is the same thing but one that breaks http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/1/

Comment: Breaks how? The class is simply missing. `ckeditor-wrapper-end != editor-wrapper-end`

Comment: I am sorry Jonathan...I just updated with the correct data that is not finding element present http://jsfiddle.net/bf6wtLav/9/